How to selecting Principled BSDF node in the shader of the selected object if blender is not set in English
I’ve a basic problem where my code does not work if Blender is not set in English
This is the piece of code that I think it’s broken:
mat1 = bpy.data.materials.get("CustomMaterial1")
bsdf1 = mat1.node_tree.nodes.get("Principled BSDF")
if bsdf1:
    bsdf1.inputs[0].default_value = (color1[0], color1[1], color1[2], 1)
    bsdf1.inputs[2].default_value = 1.0

I’ve already substituted the names of the Base colour and Roughness channels by calling input[1] and input[2] instead to make it not localized to any specific UI language, and this works, but what about the Principled BSDF name of the node?
Is there a way to call it by its type or index instead in order to make it independent from Blender UI language?

It depends on the situation how you select the node you need. You could loop through nodes until you find the right type:
import bpy

nodes = bpy.context.object.data.materials[0].node_tree.nodes

for n in nodes:
    if n.type == "BSDF_PRINCIPLED":
        node = n

node.location.x -= 100

But what if there are multiple nodes of the same type?.. It's quite common to just assign the node to a variable when creating it:
import bpy

nodes = bpy.context.object.data.materials[0].node_tree.nodes

node = nodes.new('ShaderNodeBsdfPrincipled')
node.location = (100,0)

But there are no rules or limits here, you can select the nodes by any attribute or however the situation requires.

Thanks a lot! I'm sure the principled is the only one because I've created it before, so buth methods would work I guess, thanks!
